# How do I docker buildx build into a local "registry" container

Tags: docker, buildx

I am trying to build a multi-arch image but would like to avoid pushing it to docker hub. I've had a lot of trouble finding out how to control the export options. is there a way to make "--push" push to a registry of my choosing?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you're looking for `docker buildx build --load` to load into local registry: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#load

Answer (score 0):

Images are specified using a "reference" which gets parsed to identify where the image is pushed or pulled from. That reference includes the registry, repository, and tag. If the registry is excluded, Docker Hub is used as the default. And if the tag is excluded, `latest` is used as a default. The syntax looks like:

```
registry.example.org/some/repository:tag
```

So to push your image to your own registry, you need to specify that registry in the image name that you build:

```bash
docker buildx build -t registry.example.org/some/repository:tag --push .
```

Additional configuration options for a registry can be defined in the [buildkitd.toml](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/toml-configuration/). Buildx also allows for other [output types](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#output), however, pushing to a [docker engine before the transition to containerd for image management](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/371) will only support a single platform.